# How can I Remove ' ' from the list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an output like this :

```
['', '', '', 'Color', 'Yellow', 'RBC/hpf', '4-6', 'Appereance', 'Semi', 'Turbid', 'WBC/hpf', '2-3', 'Specific', 'Gravity', '1014', 'Epithelialcells/Lpf', '1-2', 'PH', '7', 'Bacteria', '(Few)', 'Protein', 'Pos(+)', 'Casts', 'Negative', 'Glucose', 'Negative', 'Mucous', '(Few)', 'Keton', 'Negative', 'Blood', 'Pos(+)', 'Bilirubin', 'Negative', 'Urobilinogen', 'Negative']
```

Then I wanna remove '' from the list and finally I have some Continuous letters in list and how can I put them togrther? , like : semi Turbid (in the list)

Thanks :)

Comment: What about `list(filter(None, your_list))`?

Answer (score 1):

To remove '' from the list you can use

```
list2 = [i for i in list1 if i != '']
```

Then if you want to create a string from the list you can use

```
" ".join(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
b = [x for x in a if len(x)>1]
```

or this:

```
b = [x for x in a if x != '']
```

That removes the `''` sign in the second one and in the first one discards everything that has a length of less than 1.

If you want to join strings you can use `.join()` method, for example:

```
a = ['abc', 'def']
''.join(a)
'abcdef'

'-'.join(a)
'abc-def'
```

Answer (score 0):

the list class has a remove method used like this: list.remove()
to remove empty list items just type list_name.remove('')